Waswas after my salah
Assalamualaikum I have just recently started having waswas and it is really affecting me. It mostly affects me after I have completed a hard salat. Every time I do a salat I always think if I should do it again because I gets thoughts about if I did my salah correctly or not. I get mixed up with my thoughts thinking if this is shaytaan or is it just me. Due to this problem that I am having to do salahs more for example I did asr 3 times just because I had doubts and I still feel doubt. Is there anyway to get rid of waswas

Questions asking for personal advice are off-topic.
